# how to setup github repository for multiple mobile platforms

Tags: github

I have found this question [Source Control for Mobile Platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767254/best-way-to-organize-source-control-for-mobile-platforms) but it does not quite describe my specific situation so I am going to re-ask it.

I currently have a private repo where we are developing two native mobile apps (one for Android and one for iOs). I am using two different developers who do know each other and work together but ultimately one is responsible for iOs and one for Android.

At the moment I have created a single repo and invited them both as collaborators. In that repo I created two folders: one called iOS and the other Android. I have asked them to upload their source code to their respective folders. However there is a problem. When they fork the repo each developer gets a copy of the Android and ios folders. They dont really want this as each one only works on one of the platforms.

SO the question is this:
1. Do I need to create repo for each platform?
2. Perhaps there is a way for them to selectively fork a folder from a repo?
3. I am sure I am not the first person who has had to manage multiple platform development on Github. How have others done it?

Comment: If none of the source is shared between the projects, then two separate repos make sense.  You can look into submodules as an option but I don't see the advantage having everything in a single repo unless code is shared or a build system needs the entire source.